# Is open OpenGL completely broken after iOS 12.4?

Tags: c++, ios, c, objective-c, dosbox

I have an open source MS-DOS emulator for iOS here:
https://github.com/MattAndrzejczuk/MSDOS-for-iOS

This app runs well when using my older iOS devices such as the old iPhone 5S. but right after iOS 13.0 was released, the app delegate has trouble rendering SDL due to NOT calling UIKit methods on the main thread, but I'm not quite sure if this crash is due to OpenGL being completely deprecated, or, if maybe the newer SceneDelegate and AppDelegate changes which seemed to have been overhauled in iOS 13 are the cause of this issue. Just for some context, *I've noticed that I cannot create a new Xcode project with a basic hello world label and build it directly for iOS 12 devices without doing this:*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

// ADD THIS TO DEFAULT APPDELEGATE.H:
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

This solution below, only somewhat fixed the problem:

`Sources/dospad/Shared/DosEmuThread.m`

```
#import "DosEmuThread.h"

extern int SDL_main(int argc, char *argv[]);

@implementation DosEmuThread
@synthesize started;

- (void)start 
{
    if (started) {
        NSLog(@"DosEmuThread %p already started", self);
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"Start dosbox in new thread");
    started = YES;
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(run) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void) run {
    @autoreleasepool {
        
        /// UNCOMMENTING THIS SOMEWHAT FIXES THE ISSUE:
        //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            char *argv[1] = {"dosbox"};
            SDL_main(1, argv);
            self.started = NO;
        //});
        
    }
}
@end
```

This fixes the app, in that I can reach the DOS prompt, but once I try to open something like this:

`C:\ cd WAR2A`

`C:\ WAR2.EXE`

I just get stuck at a blank screen, so obviously the quick fix of putting the dos thread on the main thread will break once SDL tries to run a full screen EXE app.

I'd really like to have the ability to emulate an x86 machine to run classic DOS games and even support Windows 95 for iOS, if there are alternative git repos out there that can do something similar, please let me know.

Comment: Short answer is NO. I still haven't upgrades a few apps to Metal and as of iOS 14.4 they work perfectly. (Hoping I have at least one more upgrade cycle to move to Metal.) Sure, I use Swift - but that shouldn't matter. There are a few **warnings* I get on a new project - specifically, `GLES_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 CI_SILENCE_GL_DEPRECATION=1 in my build settings, but that is all I need to squelch them.

Comment: Separate comment, because this is likely why someone voted to close (not me) and what your issue is - third party issues. I don't use anything like that. Just trying to rule out anything like iOS 12.5. (You had me concerned because iOS 14.5 is a pretty large update and I misread things.)

Comment: It has always been a requirement to perform UI updates on the main thread. If you didn't you would get weird delays and other problems. A main thread checker was added that now warns you if you use another thread to perform UI updates. The new scene model that allows multiple views on an iPad means that the root window is somewhat deprecated but you can use it if you need to for backward compatibility reasons.  This is why you need to add the property manually.